# android call function after volley response in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am getting data from web service using volley library but I want to move to another activity when I get the data by volley response so I want to wait until i have connection response. When I used `AsyncTask`, and put the transfer function in post execution, the second activity start the the data received as I saw in log cat. and when I put the transfer function inside volley `OnResponse` the activity freezing. So how can wait until get response and save the data then move to another activity to use it.
Here is the code:

```
public class Loading_Car_info extends AppCompatActivity {

    String appUrl="https://darialkndari5.000webhostapp.com/read_info.php";
    String  user_id,name,v_date,v_no,qr_code;
    String[] phaths;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading__car_info);
        Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        MyAsyncTask m=new MyAsyncTask();
        m.execute();

        }
    public void transfer()
    {

        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("paths", phaths);
        b.putString("name","hi");
        b.putString("v_dat","hello");
        b.putString("v_no","rrr");
        b.putString("qr_code",qr_code);

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,User_Info.class);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //UI Interaction
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, appUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        boolean move=false;


                        phaths=new String[response.length()];

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("ads");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject student = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                v_date=student.getString("v_date");
                                v_no=student.getString("v_no");
                                qr_code=student.getString("Qr_code");
                                name=student.getString("name");
                                phaths[i]=student.getString("path");

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println("MainActivity 2" + error.toString());
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        params.put("id", "3");
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                NotificationData.getmInstance(Loading_Car_info.this).addrequestqueue(stringRequest);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            transfer();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call transfer after getting all your data within `onResponse()`:

```
   try {    
        JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("ads");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject student = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            v_date=student.getString("v_date");
            v_no=student.getString("v_no");
            qr_code=student.getString("Qr_code");
            name=student.getString("name");
            phaths[i]=student.getString("path");

        }

        transfer();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: When I do that, the screen freeze and logcat shows activity pause